# Is there any way to check whether a DOM element is created dynamically or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have content on the page both dynamically created after ajax request and content that were pre loaded on the page refresh.

When click a anchor tag i want to find if this particular anchor tag was created dynamically or not.

Though i solved this issue by using some logic but it would have been much more easy if i could do so in some other particular way

I did a lot of google but found known solution for this

Comment: Why not add a custom `data-*` attribute to your dynamically created elements?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a class to each dynamically created `<a>` and then write some JavaScript/JQuery to check if that class exists.

```
<a href='#' id='static'>Static</a>
<a href='#' class='ajax-dynamic' id='dynamic-1'>Dynamic 1</a>
<a href='#' class='ajax-dynamic' id='dynamic-2'>Dynamic 2</a>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('a').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   if ($(this).hasClass('ajax-dynamic')) {
     alert('anchor created dynmically');
   }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oq1zz3nj/3/